# Eclipse - install JAVA ME SDK: required items could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me

I am simply trying to install the JAVA ME SDK Tools in my Eclipse IDE. I am running on Ubuntu. Everytime I try to install it, I get the following error Message:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Java ME SDK Tools 8.3.0.201604172311 (com.oracle.jme.toolkit.feature.group 8.3.0.201604172311)
```

What could I do to get those missing "items" ?

Comment: dod ypu find solution? same here on windows

Comment: this was unanswered since 2017, clearly didnt find a solution lol

Comment: just getting back into j2me LOL.. i did manage to get it going using old wtk 2.5.2